# Multiple meta conditions on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

First of all this for a WP 3.9.1 (That's what client have and refuses to update to new version cause it have many custom plugins).
Now the client asked to implement webinars on the site and for that there is a custom type. Each webinar have a start date (past webinars should not appear on site). Now in a the landing page there for the webinars section is a list of most visited webinars (the site add another custom field programatically each time someone click on a webinar detail or register link).
So basically I need to return all webinars ordered by visited field desc and having the start date greater than today.

I tried many conbinations but none brings all results with that conditions, the closer a get is:

```
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'site_webinars',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'webinar_visit_counts',
        'meta_query' => 
        [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
                'key' => 'fecha_de_inicio_webinar',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'compare' => ">"
            ],
            [
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'webinar_visit' => [
                    'key' => 'webinar_visit_counts',
                    'value' => 0,
                    'compare' => ">"
                ],
                'webinar_visit_2' => [
                    'key' => 'webinar_visit_counts',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => "NOT EXISTS"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value'
    ];
```

but it looks inspecting the query that is only using the "fecha_de_inicio_webinar" condition and searching just for the posts that have "webinar_visit_counts" key. So for example if I have 20 webinars total, but only 7 have that key (the other 3 haven't been visited) the query just returns 7 even when I need to return 10 (post_per_page is 10 by default if I'm correct).

Ideally I will need to return 10 ordered for webinar_visit_counts desc, fecha_de_inicio_webinar asc up to 10 even if webinar_visit_counts is 0 or don't yet exists for the content type.

It's even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to get `NOT EXISTS` the first. check the below code.

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'site_webinars',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'webinar_visit_counts',
    'meta_query' => 
    [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key' => 'fecha_de_inicio_webinar',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => ">"
        ],
        [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            'webinar_visit' => [
                'key' => 'webinar_visit_counts',
                'compare' => "NOT EXISTS",
                'value' => ''
            ]
            'webinar_visit' => [
                'key' => 'webinar_visit_counts',
                'value' => 0,
                'compare' => ">"
            ],
            
        ]
    ],
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
];
```

Or you can also try to update `webinar_visit_counts` to 0 for not visited webinars. check the below code.

```
function update_webinar_visit_counts_for_not_exist(){

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'site_webinars',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'webinar_visit_counts',
                'compare' => "NOT EXISTS"
            )
        )
    );

    $webinars = new WP_Query( $args );
     
    if ( $webinars->have_posts() ) { while ( $webinars->have_posts() ) { $webinars->the_post();
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'webinar_visit_counts', 0 );
    } 
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_action( 'init', 'update_webinar_visit_counts_for_not_exist', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Sorry, was out. Nop, it returns the same result set.